# How to separate list values in nested list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, split, nested-lists

I have to read RINEX observation file and compare with satellite informations.
Until now, I read some data. So, I have a nested list. I have to separate this list values by comma and put 'None' in spaces. List is like this;

```
oblst = [['  22527689.086 7                   -578290.975 7   -410051.96348  22527682.94948\n', 
          '  20593906.672 7                   -142315.266 7   -103992.19948  20593902.01648\n', 
          '  22312367.273 6  22312363.496 9   -573672.801 6   -426591.952 9  22312363.52047\n', 
          '  24649943.453 3                   -696710.409 3   -499047.10745  24649943.55545\n', 
          '  21574180.359 7                   -440212.809 7   -323130.81248  21574175.09448\n', 
          '  20159532.789 7                     35621.205 7     26243.45049  20159527.23449\n', 
          '  24435415.719 6  24435413.602 9    417737.346 6    319304.620 9  24435413.80147\n', 
          '  23108319.461 5                    344109.572 5    249072.03046  23108315.90646\n', 
          '  21789481.414 7                    326180.505 7    238895.05548  21789474.12548\n', 
          '  21975436.727 7                    277875.380 7    205734.181 8  21975443.121 8\n', 
          '  19981973.117 9                   -127270.254 9    -94211.274 9  19981980.414 9\n', 
          '  21682862.406 6                    242033.680 6    179454.101 8  21682869.020 8\n', 
          '  20647552.734 7                   -446216.926 7   -329944.882 9  20647562.945 9\n', 
          '  23174371.141 6                   -645644.090 6   -481288.202 8  23174379.656 8\n', 
          '  21946454.047 6                    420271.088 6    311362.996 8  21946462.590 8\n', 
          '  21922170.063 8                   -124733.763 8    -92183.249 9  21922177.883 9\n'],
          [......],[......]]
```

I'd like to print like this;

```
oblst = [['22527689.086 7','None','-578290.975 7','-410051.96348','22527682.94948', 
          '20593906.672 7','None','-142315.266 7','-103992.19948','20593902.01648', 
          '22312367.273 6','22312363.496 9','-573672.801 6','-426591.952 9','22312363.52047',
         ......],[...]]
```

Finally, if I print oblst[0][1], I want to print like this;

```
'22527689.086 7'
```

I tried to this using for-loop. This is what I wrote code.

```
  for lines in oblst:
    result = []
    for line in lines:
        for k in range(0, len(line)-1, 16):
            numbers = line[k:k+16].strip()
            result.append(numbers if numbers else None)
    print result
```

output was like this; it was not bad.

```
result = ['22527689.086 7', 'None', '-578290.975 7', '-410051.96348', '22527682.94948', 
          '20593906.672 7', 'None', '-142315.266 7', '-103992.19948', '20593902.01648', 
          '22312367.273 6', '22312363.496 9', '-573672.801 6', '-426591.952 9', '22312363.52047', 
          '24649943.453 3', 'None', '-696710.409 3',...][....]]
```

but I printed result[0]. It was first values each lists. Indexes set vertically.

```
22527689.086 7
22524473.070 7
22521257.078 7
22518041.602 7
22514825.805 7
22511610.484 7
      .
      .
      .
```

I really appreciate that you may help or give any advice for me.
Please help or any advice for me.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? [so] is not a code writing service: show us some effort and we'll help you out.

Comment: But I do not see any comma in your initial list. Please update the example you have provided.

Comment: @anonymous, that's part of the OPs request, "I have to separate this list values by comma ..."

Comment: @downshift *I have to separate this list values by comma* For achieving this, there should be comma `,` present in the content of the list. Check the required list example for clarity.

Comment: @anonymous Originally, There are not commas. I read RINEX observation file(.11o format). So, It's not separated by comma originally. If I may say so, it's separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How rigid is the structure? If it is very rigid then here's an example of converting the first item to a list meeting your requirement. However, this is very fragile:

```
>>> [s.strip() for s in '  None'.join(s.strip().split('                 ')).split('  ')]
['22527689.086 7', 'None', '-578290.975 7', '-410051.96348', '22527682.94948']
```

If you want to convert this back to a string with `,`s then:

```
>>> ', '.join(s.strip() for s in '  None'.join(s.strip().split('                 ')).split('  '))
'22527689.086 7, None, -578290.975 7, -410051.96348, 22527682.94948'
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help!